# LyX: add multiple authors

Tags: lyx, titles

In Lyx, I have to insert 3 authors in an article. For each one of them I will have to specify their email address and the university they belong to. Two belong to the same one:

```
author_a, author_a@email.com, university_1
author_b, author_b@email.com, university_2
author_c, author_c@email.com, university_2
```

How do I do this in Lyx? I tried looking at [this](http://wiki.lyx.org/FAQ/MultipleAuthors), but it's quite confusing.  Could anybody write me step-by-step how to do this?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I am not a LyX user, but I would strongly suspect this depends on which document class you are using.  Can you provide that information?

Comment: 2 years and a half later, not really! ;)

Comment: I don't understand your comment.  Looking at the answers below the low level `\and` is an appropriate solution for `article` but not for `amsart` where mark up of multiple authors is radically different.

Comment: My question is from September 2012. Thank you for your interest, but... I've moved on since then! :D

Comment: Ah, I see - I didn't look at the edit history.  However, questions and answers here are meant to be of use to future visitors, so I think it would be good if the question stated which set of document classes you wish answers to apply to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Or use forced newlines (`CTRL+Enter`)
[image: Multiple authors with newlines]

Easy as that ;)

Comment: that does work. Is that a standard way of doing this? (I'm asking, I don't know!) Often I see authors' names  with affiliations below.

Answer (score 1):

choose from the paragraph menu `author`. Then insert the name of author_A, then choose a footnote from the menu and insert in this footnote an URL (from insert->URL) and after elaving the url window the University as normal text. Now Leave the footnote window and insert with Ctrl-L the LaTeX code (Evil Red Text)
`\and`. Now do the same for author_B and author_D without leaving the author field.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I did as you said, but the `\and` operator is hiding everything there is before. I mean, in the resulting pdf file, I only see author C. 
Anyhow, the footnotes are appearing in the bottom of the page, which is not what I was looking for. They should be right below the author name, right? Either all together, or more neatly below the corresponding person.

Comment: then use a tabular for every author for name and email.

Comment: I can't see the reason for using footnotes. Does the question state anything like that? Or do you mean to reference them? In which case I would use a bibliography, such as Bibtex

Comment: A `\footnote` in the authors part is automatically converted into a `\thanks` command which should be used by default!

Comment: it doesn't seem to work here anyway

Comment: do you need some special document class for that to work or am I especially unlucky?

Answer (score -1):

```
Author one \and{ Author two } \and{ Author three }
```

Just add the accolades in LaTeX code and it will work.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! This syntax is slightly wrong I'm afraid, it should be `Author one \and Author two \and Author three`. The `\and` command does take an argument, it is just a separator.

Comment: (I meant to say 'does *not* take an argument'.)