# How to add multi-authors with different affiliations in Beamer using LyX?

Tags: beamer, lyx, titles

I want to have two authors with different affiliations showing on the cover page in `beamer`. Can anyone help me how I can do this in LyX? Specifically, I want to have the below structure:

```
    Title

   Author1 
Affiliation1

   Author2 
Affiliation2

Conference 
   Date
```

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73212/lyx-add-multiple-authors - do either of these answers work for you?

Comment: Actually I want to put the affiliation just below the author and two authors are placed separately. So the order will be Author1 // Affiliation1 // Author2 // Affiliation2. The above article does not provide such a solution.

Comment: What about using forced newlines to separate affiliation from author, and using two forced newlines to separate the 2nd author block from the first?

Comment: It will give a compiling error if I insert \newline in \author{}.

Answer (score 2):

Finally, I managed to solve my own question, although it does now look as nice as what I expected.

[image]

After compiling, one can have

[image]