# How to present two sets of authors in beamer

Tags: beamer

I am giving a talk on two different papers. I would like to present the sets of authors separately, one above the other, on the title page.  The following doesn't work but hopefully shows my intent.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{default}
\title{The title}
\author[Us]{First Author\inst{1} \and Second Author\inst{2}}
\institute{\inst{1} University of Us1 \and \inst{2} University of Us2}
\author[Them]{Another Author\inst{3} \and Yet Another Author\inst{2}}
\institute{\inst{3} University of Them1 \and \inst{2} University of Them2}
\date{}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\maketitle
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The layout I would like is:

```
First group of authors
First group of institutions
Second group of authors
Second group of institutions
```

Comment: Hi,  have you seen these links? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/163190/beamer-multiple-authors-formatting-the-title-page, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/114216/how-to-add-multi-authors-with-different-affiliations-in-beamer-using-lyx

Comment: @Sebastiano Yes thank you. I want something a little different. I would like the authors and institutions to look as they would normally on the title page, just one group on top of the next. So a) first lot of authors then b) first lot of institutions then c) second lot of authors then d) second lot of institutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define your own title page:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\title{The title}
\date{}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{title page}{%
  \vbox{}
  \vfill
  \begingroup
    \centering
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center]{title}
      \usebeamerfont{title}\inserttitle\par%
      \ifx\insertsubtitle\@empty%
      \else%
        \vskip0.25em%
        {\usebeamerfont{subtitle}\usebeamercolor[fg]{subtitle}\insertsubtitle\par}%
      \fi%     
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \vskip1em\par
    \author[Us]{First Author\inst{1} \and Second Author\inst{2}}
    \institute{\inst{1} University of Us1 \and \inst{2} University of Us2}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center]{author}
      \usebeamerfont{author}\insertauthor
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center]{institute}
      \usebeamerfont{institute}\insertinstitute
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \author[Them]{Another Author\inst{3} \and Yet Another Author\inst{2}}
    \institute{\inst{3} University of Them1 \and \inst{2} University of Them2}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center]{author}
      \usebeamerfont{author}\insertauthor
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center]{institute}
      \usebeamerfont{institute}\insertinstitute
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center]{date}
      \usebeamerfont{date}\insertdate
    \end{beamercolorbox}\vskip0.5em
    {\usebeamercolor[fg]{titlegraphic}\inserttitlegraphic\par}
  \endgroup
  \vfill
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\maketitle
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]