# How can I add names on the right and left hand side of the title page?

Tags: beamer, titles

I want to add my supervisor's name and on the left side and my advisory committee members' names to the left side of my `beamer` title page? Kindly tell me how can I do that. Currently it is like this,

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=149]{beamer}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\title{Something}
\author{Someone}

\institute{\textsc{Somewhere}}
\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \maketitle
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Very recently, we had a very similar question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/622753/47927). See also: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/393310/47927 or https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/163190/47927 or https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/114216/47927 .

Comment: You don't HAVE to use \maketitle.  It is supposed to make the title page easier, but often makes it harder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example is given if you find it useful.

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=149]{beamer}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\title{Something}
\author{Someone}

\institute{\textsc{Somewhere}}
\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \maketitle
        \begin{columns}[t]
        
        \begin{column}{.5\textwidth}
          \hspace*{10mm} Mr. X\\
          \hspace*{10mm} X College
        \end{column}
        \begin{column}{.5\textwidth}
          Mr. Y\\
          X College
        \end{column}
        \end{columns}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This worked, thank you so much sir..